# Why Azure Web App main slot pointing to sub-slot?

Tags: .net, angular, azure, cloud

I have deployed my angular application on the Azure web app main slot and my APIs are deployed on second slot of the same web app. But the Main app URL is loading second i.e. API app. What I might be doing wrong here.
I am deploying Web App on the main slot through FTP Client and API on the second slot, through VS 2019.

Comment: First of all: that's not what slots are meant for. They are for creating a staging environment where you can test new versions of the same application. As far as your question goes: it sounds like you either deployed to the production slot from Visual Studio, or a swap was triggered after that deployment.

Comment: Sounds like those two should be separate apps in the same app service plan instead of slots, yeah.

Comment: You must have misused the usage of slot, what you need should be a virtual application.

Comment: You can refer my answer, I think it useful to u.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63982446/how-to-deploy-a-flaskreact-application-to-azure-web-service/63985149#63985149

Comment: Thank you all, @JasonPan you are right. I was doing the wrong things with Slots. Now I am hosting APP and API separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure web app, generally we developers will create `dev slot` and `production slot`. The role of Slot is to update the latest version of the program online, the original webapp program does not crash, a way for `hot deployment`.

In `dev slot`, we can develop and test. In the `production slot`, we generally do not easily modify the code-related content.

You mentioned in the Comment that you have used two separate webapps to host app and api. This is possible, but if you don't want to create two webapps, you can [use virtual application in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63982446/how-to-deploy-a-flaskreact-application-to-azure-web-service/63985149#63985149).