# Deploy ReactJs and Python project AZURE

Tags: python, reactjs, linux, azure, deployment

Goal: deploy reactjs (front) and python (back) project on Azure VM Linux (Ubuntu 18.04)

I have a project folder where I have two subdirectories: one named front and one names back.
To launch it on my local computer (linux 18.04) I do the following steps:

To start the back

- cd back
- flask run

To start the front

- cd front
- npm start

Then go to http://localhost:3000/ (redirected automatically there after launching npm start)

I need to deploy now my project using Azure. So I have access to an Azure VM that has Ubuntu 18.04 on it which I can access using SSH from my local computer.
How am I supposed to deploy this project on the VM? Do I need to simply do the same as on my local machine (flask run and npm start)?

PS: It is the first time I deploy a project.

Comment: Hey Azure VM is not suitable for a developer to host their site..

Comment: Why don't you try PAAS (Azure App Service)?

Comment: You can easily deploy your app via github actions..

Comment: Please don't use Azure VM because of high cost..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You can use Azure App Services to achieve your needs (choose Windows platform when creating it).***

## Advantage:

1. Easy to deploy, azure web app has many mature tools to monitor programs, record logs, etc.
2. The cost is low compared to VM.
3. If you use Premium App Service plan, webapp will be backed up regularly. (Excluding data in the database, only for files under wwwroot)

## Related Post:

[How to deploy a Flask+React application to Azure Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63982446/how-to-deploy-a-flaskreact-application-to-azure-web-service/63985149#63985149)