# How we can deploy a Flask + React Application to Azure?

Tags: python, reactjs, azure, flask

I want to create a machine learning app with Flask as backend and keep React JS as the front-end. Though I found couple of tutorials how to do that but there are very few in terms of deployment. I want to deploy and host a Flask+ReactJS app to Azure cloud. Is there any good tutorial or link which I can follow. I have been struggling for days now.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the above requirement you can find the below mentioned sample resource to create and host flask and react app in AZURE.

To do that we will need to setup the flask app as backend and then React app.

Please refer this [***BLOG***](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-deploy-a-react-flask-app-47a89a5d17d9) for complete setup to build.

For more information you can refer the below links:-

- ***SO THREAD***: [***How to deploy a Flask+React application to Azure Web Service***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63982446/how-to-deploy-a-flaskreact-application-to-azure-web-service)
- ***BLOG:-*** [***Deploy your Flask app on Azure***](https://medium.com/@nikovrdoljak/deploy-your-flask-app-on-azure-in-3-easy-steps-b2fe388a589e) & [***How to automate Python/Flask deployment to Azure App Service***](https://buddy.works/guides/python-flask)